# How to save data in java object querying from mongodb aggregate

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

**My code :**

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "countryId" : 1,
        "countryName" : "Hong Kong"
    },
    "cities" : [
        {
            "cityId" : 1,
            "cityName" : "Hong Kong",
            "sites" : [
                {
                    "siteId" : 1,
                    "siteName" : "Kong Centre"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the sample json. I am working on a project where i have to get sites based on countries and cities. I am able to set country id and country name in my java custom object but unable to fetch "cities" & "sites" embedded array. Please assist.

Comment: Please take a bit of time to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question to increase the chances of getting good replies.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can find out cities and sites data using JSOnObject and JSONArray.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonRead {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\aq104e\\Desktop\\text.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray jsonArrayOfCities = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cities");

            for (Object jsonObjectOfCities : jsonArrayOfCities) {
                JSONObject city = (JSONObject) jsonObjectOfCities;
                String cityid = String.valueOf(city.get("cityId"));

                JSONArray jsonArrayOfSites = (JSONArray) city.get("sites");

                for (Object jsonObjectOfSites : jsonArrayOfSites) {
                    JSONObject jsonLineItem = (JSONObject) jsonObjectOfSites;
                    String siteId = String.valueOf(jsonLineItem.get("siteId"));
                    String siteName = String.valueOf(jsonLineItem.get("siteName"));

                    System.out.println("site Id is " + siteId);

                    System.out.println("siteName is " +siteName);
                }
                String cityName = (String) city.get("cityName");

                System.out.println("City id -> " + cityid);
                System.out.println("city name is -> " + cityName);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```